# NX Angular Mono repo, using process.env

Tags: angular, nx-monorepo

I am using NX and angular for my project and now I need to add some secrets. I was reading:

https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/use-environment-variables-in-angular

and figured this would work well, so I followed the instructions on that page.
I don't seem to have any issues using `process.env` in my `.ts` files for the application, but when I try to use in my associated library, I get this error:

[image]

The annoying thing is, both my application `ts.config` and the library `ts.config` has `types: ["node"]` defined. Does anyone know what I can do to get this to work?

Comment: What "secrets" do you want to store? It's a frontend webapp. Anyone who visits your website can view them...

Comment: we use an API key for testing locally. It's not used when deployed at all; so rather than commit this to the repo, we want to use .env